# UIImagePickerController dismiss doesn't work on iPhone 5S

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, iphone-5

I am using the `UIImagePickerController` to take a picture on an iPhone 5S.
I can present it alright as a modal with

```
[self.navigationController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

But when I want to dismiss it in the delegate methods it doesn't work. And the memory builds up memory up 300 MB (before that it was at 25 MB).
I dismiss it like this :

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{}];
```

The code works fine on iPhone 5.

Here is how I initialize it :

`UIImagePickerController* picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; picker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext; 
picker.delegate = self; 
picker.allowsEditing = NO; 
[self.navigationController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:^{}];`

Comment: Could you try with [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]?

Comment: Already tried that. nothing either.

Comment: I have two things in my mind to try. First, use [self] instead of [self.navigationController]. Second, make sure that delegate method is called.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to have a completion handler, pass in nil instead of ^{}.

```
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```